# How to convert from functional component to a class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I'm making a speech recognition for my collaborative whiteboard. My whiteboard component is a class component and I want to put the code of the speech recognition  (which is a functional component), in the whiteboard component. But for that I need it to be converted to a class component. I am using library `react-speech-recognition`
This is the code which needs to be converted:

```
import React from 'react'
import SpeechRecognition, { useSpeechRecognition } from 'react-speech-recognition'

const Mic = () => {
    const { transcript, resetTranscript } = useSpeechRecognition()

    if (!SpeechRecognition.browserSupportsSpeechRecognition()) {
        return null
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
            <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
            <p>{transcript}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Mic
```

Can anyone show me how to do it? With the speech recognition function at the `transcript` and `resetTranscript` variable makes it harder for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your hook `useSpeechRecognition`, you can't use it inside the class component, you can check the React doc to verify: [Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html), as an alternative you should use HOC `SpeechRecognition`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import SpeechRecognition from 'react-speech-recognition'

class Mic extends Component {
  render() {
    const { transcript, resetTranscript, browserSupportsSpeechRecognition } = this.props

    if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
      return null
    }
    
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
        <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
        <p>{transcript}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SpeechRecognition(Mic)
```